# Looking for LaTeX file for Bear's Neuroscience

Tags: templates

I'm looking for the certain LaTeX style file that was used for Bear's "*Neuroscience: Exploring the Brain*" (4th Edition). I have attached a screenshot of one of the pages of the book. [image]

Comment: Do you know that the book was typeset using LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, I am more or less sure that it was. Furthermore, the use of Computer Modern is rarely used if not typesetting in (La)TeX

Comment: Have you considered contacting the author or the book's publisher?

Comment: @jade, why not contacting the publisher? Many times they do provide templates, may be even for LaTeX ... https://authors.jblearning.com/welcome.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I will try that! Thank you for not downvoting this question as well.

Comment: the samples at https://www.jblearning.com/catalog/productdetails/9781284211283#productInfo  are set with inDesign not latex